# How to handle prisma errors and send a valid message to client?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, error-handling, prisma

I'm using Prisma as my ORM  for (postgres) in a node.js project and i have been unable to properly send **Prisma Error Message** to client.

My code

```js
router.post("/abc", async (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  const resp = await primsa.tableName.create({ data: data });
  res.status(200).send({ message: "Success", resp, loanDetails });
});
```

The **`(err instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientValidationError)`** // true
Error Message from `err.message`

```js
Invalid `primsa.tableName.create()` invocation in
/Users/xx/Projects/xx/routes/xx.js:11:43
   8 const data = req.body;
  10 console.log(details);
→ 11 const resp = await primsa.tableName.create({
       data: {
         user: '2',
               ~~~
         email: 'xyz@xxxx.xxx',
         mobile: 1234567890,
 
       }
     })

Argument user: Got invalid value '2' on prisma.createTableName. Provided String, expected usersCreateNestedOneWithouttableNameInput:
type usersCreateNestedOneWithoutTableNameInput {
  create?: usersCreateWithoutTableNameInput | usersUncheckedCreateWithoutTableNameInput
  connectOrCreate?: usersCreateOrConnectWithoutTableNameInput
  connect?: usersWhereUniqueInput
}
```

**The Problem Is**

I' only want the **Argument** part from the `err.message`, but it provides the whole code and other data in the `err.messsage` itself.

Answer (score 5):

This is my global errorHandling file If it get back to me if it could help. It's really hectic handling errors in prisma but hope this is the solution you need thx.

```
import CustomError from '../utils/customError.js'
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';


const handlePrismaError = (err) => {
    switch (err.code) {
        case 'P2002':
            // handling duplicate key errors
            return new CustomError(`Duplicate field value: ${err.meta.target}`, 400);
        case 'P2014':
            // handling invalid id errors
            return new CustomError(`Invalid ID: ${err.meta.target}`, 400);
        case 'P2003':
            // handling invalid data errors
            return new CustomError(`Invalid input data: ${err.meta.target}`, 400);
        default:
            // handling all other errors
            return new CustomError(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`, 500);
    }
};

const handleJWTError = () => new CustomError('Invalid token please login again', 400);

const handleJWTExpiredError = () => new CustomError('Token has expired please login again', 400);

const sendErrorDev = (err, req, res) => {
    if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')) {
        res.status(err.statusCode).json({
            status: err.status,
            errors: err,
            message: err.message,
            stack: err.stack,
        });
    } else {
        //rendered website
        res.status(err.statusCode).render('error', { title: 'Something went wrong!', msg: err.message });
    }
};

const sendErrorProd = (err, req, res) => {


    if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')) {
        if (err.isOperational)
            return res.status(err.statusCode).json({ status: err.status, message: err.message });

        //programming errors dont leak details
        console.error('ERROR ', err);

        return res.status(400).json({ status: ' error', message: 'Please try again later' });
    }

    //for rendered website
    if (err.isOperational)
        return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
            status: err.status,
            message: err.message,
        });
    //programming errors should not leak details to client

    return res.status(500).json({ status: ' error', message: 'Sommething went wrong' });
};

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {

    err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500; //default status code for an error
    err.status = err.status || 'error'; //default status
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        sendErrorDev(err, req, res);
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        let error = { ...err };

        error.message = err.message;
        if (err instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
            console.log("handlePrismaError")
            error = handlePrismaError(err);

        } else if (error.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
            error = handleJWTError();
        } else if (error.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
            error = handleJWTExpiredError();
        }
        sendErrorProd(error, req, res);
    }
};

export default errorHandler
```

Comment: So u can do other possible error checks like for PrismaClientValidationError